# How can I select last by group where something in SAS

Tags: sql, select, sas

Say I have a table `Tbl` that is sorted by 3 columns `{a,b,c}` I also have another 100 columns, one of them is `d`. How can I flag the `last row by a group such that d=something`, the flag shall be a new column. Hopefully this is doable withOUT re-sorting the whole table

```
a b c ...many columns... d IDX
1                        5 1                        
1                        3 2
1                        3 3
2                        3 4 
2                        3 5
2                        2 6
2                        2 7
```

On this table we want to add another column `newCol` to flag the `last row by group a where d = 3`

```
a b c ...many columns... d IDX newCol
1                        5 1   0                     
1                        3 2   0
1                        3 3   1
2                        3 4   0
2                        3 5   1
2                        2 6   0
2                        2 7   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data want;
set have;
by a d notsorted;
if last.d and d=3 then flag=1;
run;
```

This requires the dataset to be sorted in a useful fashion - it doesn't have to be in order by d, but it does have to have all the d's of one value together (ie, not `3 3 1 3 4 1 2 3` but `3 3 3 3 4 1 1 2` is fine).

If that's not the case, then there isn't a solution that doesn't rely on sorting in some fashion, whether it be SQL (which does sort the data, it just doesn't tell you it's doing it), `PROC SORT`, or a hash table (which if you can fit everything into memory might be the fastest sort).

Comment: Interesting ! thanks for this unsorted stuff I did not know about, unfortunately `d` is not grouped as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this gets implemented, but the following does the work that you want:

```
proc sql;
    select a, b, c, . . .
    from t
    group by a, b
    having c = max(c);
```

Note that this syntax is quite specific to SAS proc sql.  It is not ANSI standard and will not work in most other databases.

This uses a process called "remerging".  I'm not sure if it resorts the original table.

EDIT:

Flagging the lines is just as easy:

```
proc sql;
    select a, b, c, (case when c = max(c) then 'Y' else 'N' end) as flag, . . .
    from t
    group by a, b;
```

However, if the data is already sorted, it is probably more efficient to use a data step for this purpose.